# How to make a connection between an external mysql database and then call in for specific data queries

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a springboot project and I am a total newbie in this. We are told to complete the project within a given time period and the deadline is in 3 days. I have a string which will contain the `username`. I am said that there will be an external database from where we have to fetch the data of that user and return that to the application. We are working on a web api.

Till now I have somehow extracted the username from the encoded data but now I am unable to proceed further. All the resources available online are related to building a repository and their own data and use that in the program but I have to use it from an external database. I don't know anything about this and is completely stuck.

The external database is a sample and includes an id , username and data. From the username we have to search the database and return all the three details as a JSON format of that user. 
Well that was simple in SQL but I don't know how that can be performed from the point where I am now.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

There is a special file called **application.properties** in Spring Boot, where you can define your authorization data to get connection with your remote database.

Usually, you should specify basic data:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://url-to-your-external-db/name-of-db
spring.datasource.username=your_username
spring.datasource.password=your_pasword
```

After that, you could retrieve your data from database using **JpaRepository** for example. There is plenty of frameworks that will serialize/deserialize your Java objects/entities to JSON (**Jackson** for example).

Example of fetching users from a database using JpaRepository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

     List<User> findByFirstName(String firstName)

}
```

where **User** could be your POJO which represents a table  with users in database.